# what is the mistake in usage of countifs in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif, microsoft-excel-2019

I am trying to count number of objects category orbit and criteria > 10 here is my excel sheet
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17_aKgd5__R3o4mUMy2sJAuIwpk42aEol/view?usp=sharing

I used following way `COUNTIFS function =COUNTIFS(C5:C102,"orbit",F5:F100,">10")`
but I did not get answer I get
[#Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faOIU.png)

The formula is used in Q9 cell.
What mistake I am doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The formula is used in Q9 cell. What mistake I am doing here.

Formula in Q9 is `=K11`, the formula you are referring to appears to be located in L50.

The formula reads

```
=COUNTIFS(C36:C101,"orbit",F36:F57,">10")
```

The mistake is that you have ranges of different length.

From [COUNTIFS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) :

> Important: **Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument**. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

If I adjust the formula so that both ranges have the same length, it provides a result as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am a new comer to excel so these things are a bit tricky for me to understand.